# developer-getting-started/HelloWorld.java does not compile

Tags: java, maven, graphdb

I downloaded and installed the GraphDB distribution "graphdb-free-8.5.0" (Run GraphDB as a desktop installation). In GraphDB documentation there is a discussion in *Section 6.5 Programming with GraphDB* about two examples, `HelloWorld.java` and `FamilyRelationsApp.java`.

After execution `mvn install` in path `examples/maven-installer`, as Section 6.5 dictates, then I tried to compile `HelloWorld.java` and I got the following errors:

```
HelloWorld.java:3: error: package com.ontotext.graphdb.example.util does not exist
import com.ontotext.graphdb.example.util.EmbeddedGraphDB;
                                        ^
HelloWorld.java:4: error: package org.eclipse.rdf4j.model does not exist
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Value;
                              ^
HelloWorld.java:5: error: package org.eclipse.rdf4j.query does not exist
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.*;
^
HelloWorld.java:6: error: package org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository does not exist
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.RepositoryConnection;
                                   ^
HelloWorld.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        RepositoryConnection connection = EmbeddedGraphDB.openConnectionToTemporaryRepository("rdfs");
        ^
  symbol:   class RepositoryConnection
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        RepositoryConnection connection = EmbeddedGraphDB.openConnectionToTemporaryRepository("rdfs");
                                          ^
  symbol:   variable EmbeddedGraphDB
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
            TupleQuery tupleQuery = connection.prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL,
            ^
  symbol:   class TupleQuery
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
            TupleQuery tupleQuery = connection.prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL,
                                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable QueryLanguage
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
            TupleQueryResult tupleQueryResult = tupleQuery.evaluate();
            ^
  symbol:   class TupleQueryResult
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
                BindingSet bindingSet = tupleQueryResult.next();
                ^
  symbol:   class BindingSet
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
                for (Binding binding : bindingSet) {
                     ^
  symbol:   class Binding
  location: class HelloWorld
HelloWorld.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
                    Value value = binding.getValue();
                    ^
  symbol:   class Value
  location: class HelloWorld
12 errors
```

The `pom.xml` file is the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ontotext.graphdb.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-installer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Maven installer for GraphDB</name>

    <description>
        This simple pom file can be used to install the GraphDB runtime
        dependency (of the form graphdb-[edition]-runtime-x.y.z.jar) into
        the local Maven repository. Just run "mvn install".
    </description>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Install the jar file from the lib directory -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-install</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-graphdb</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/../../lib/graphdb-free-runtime-8.5.0.jar</file>
                            <pomFile>${project.basedir}/graphdb-free-runtime.pom</pomFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

As I said, I did `mvn install` and I had a successful build. Yet, I do not know how to execute the `HelloWorld.java`. What is the process that I must follow so as to can execute the java files included in GraphDB distribution "graphdb-free-8.5.0"?

Comment: `mvn install` already compiles the classes, so what other commands are you trying to run?

Comment: My purpose is to execute HelloWorld.java from command line. When I type 'javac HellowWorld.java', it outputs the above. When I type 'java HellowWorld', it outputs Could not find or load main class HelloWorld.java

Comment: The project is using Maven to compile your project.  If you look at the pom.xml file in your project you will see some jar files that are necessary for successful compilation.  Simply by typing  `javac HellowWorld.java` is not enough

Comment: So you have successfully compiled the graph code (whatever that is) into a jar and this have been put into your Maven repository.  I have no idea what `HelloWorld` does but I guess that it uses the jar file.  I suggest that you either create a new maven project which references the jar and copy the helloworld code into that project.  Alternatively just create a simple standalone project which have the jar on its build and classpath

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how do such things. I just read GraphDB documentation and expected to execute without problems the distribution provided examples (like `HelloWorld.java`). I am not familiar with maven. Could you provide a command line complete process about how to create a maven project, write a java file that connects with GraphDB and then execute it? Also, `HelloWorld.java` is not my program, is included under developer-getting-started folder in GraphDB distributions folder. So, I expected an easy way to execute java files within that distribution.

Comment: The code already compiled if `mvn install` didn't fail. You need to learn how to run a JAR file that contains your HelloWorld class... That's the only way this code will run correctly. The JAR file is most likely within the `target` folder after you run `mvn package`. There's no need to run `mvn install`

Answer (score 0):

> Since GraphDB is not available from Maven Central (the public Maven repository), you have to install the GraphDB runtime jar into your local Maven repository.
>
> To do that, go to the examples/maven-installer subdirectory of the distribution and run:
>
> ```
>    mvn install
> ```

Okay, so you did that... And it must've worked.

(Sidenote: [that documentation seems wrong. The runtime is in Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ontotext.graphdb/graphdb-free-runtime/8.5.0))

Now, I would suggest you open the examples from your favorite IDE (Eclipse, Intellij, Netbeans, etc) **as a Maven project**, and try to run HelloWorld from there.

You don't necessarily need to know how Maven works, but it would help. For starters, it helps manage external libraries and compiles projects for you. Basically, `javac HelloWorld.java` is definitely not enough. At the very least, you need to establish the classpath (using the GraphDB JAR file(s) that Maven installed) and the correct package name of the classes of the project.

Answer (score -1):

Add these lines after the `<build>` tag inside `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ontotext.graphdb</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphdb-free-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: It does not work. When I do `mvn install`, it output errors! Unrecognised tag: 'dependencies' and stuff like that.

Answer (score -2):

Somehow, you're missing dependencies. Are you sure you have the dependency `graphdb-free-8.5.0` declared inside your `pom.xml`?

Comment: What is pom.xml? Sorry, I have no idea about that